# Blazor validation of List of Child Components

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-validation

I am trying to implement the `ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator` with a list of child components in Blazor. A list of `Animals` is bound in a form, rendered by a for loop. One of the properties of the Child class is Required.
This is the code:

`Test.razor`

```
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@page  "/Test"
@code {
    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass()
        {
            Animals = new List<AnimalItem>();
        }
        [Required]
        public string FormName { get; set; }
        public IList<AnimalItem> Animals { get; set; }
    }

    public class AnimalItem
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        MyFormData = new MyClass()
        {
            Animals = new List<AnimalItem>()
            {
                new AnimalItem { Name = "Fuffy" },
                new AnimalItem { Name = "Flaffy" }
            }
        };
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    public MyClass MyFormData { get; set; }

    private void OnValidSubmit()
    {
    }
}

<EditForm Model="MyFormData" OnValidSubmit="@OnValidSubmit" >
    <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary /> 
    <InputText type="text" @bind-Value="MyFormData.FormName"/>
    @foreach (var animal in MyFormData.Animals)
    {
        <Animal AnimalItem="animal"></Animal>
    }
    <button type="submit">Post</button>
</EditForm>
```

This is my component:

`Animal.razor`

```
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Test.AnimalItem AnimalItem { get; set; }
}
<label for="Animal">Animal</label>
<InputText  id="Animal" type="text" @bind-Value="@AnimalItem.Name" />
```

When I edit the components list and clear up the Name field, the form correctly informs me that the Name property is required. However, this doesn't prevent me from saving it if I press the submit button.
What am I doing wrong? Any advice on how to debug the validation in Blazor is welcome :)

Thanks

Comment: You need not implement the ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator in your current sample.

Comment: @enet sorry I missed your comment. what do you mean? without the `ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator ` only the top-level is validated

Comment: I mean that your code can never work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may need to add `[ValidateComplexType]` to the `Animals` collection on `MyClass`

```cs
    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass()
        {
            Animals = new List<AnimalItem>();
        }
        [Required]
        public string FormName { get; set; }
        [ValidateComplexType]
        public IList<AnimalItem> Animals { get; set; }
    }
```

[MS Docs Section on Complex Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#nested-models-collection-types-and-complex-types)

Comment: I edited the answer as the attribute needs to go on the collection property. Thanks a lot for direct me to the solution!

Comment: No problem.   :-)

Comment: Package needed: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation